# comma separated string to an array Pentaho to mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, pentaho

I am using Pentaho data integration software to transfer data into the mongodb. My original data is in an Excel format where one of the fields contains a list of strings that is comma separated. I want to split all comma separated strings into an array and then load it into the mongodb.

My excel field is:

```
participant : user1, user2, user3, user4
```

I want this to be changed like below and then to be loaded into the mongodb:

```
"participant": ["user1", "user2", "user3", "user4"]
```

I have used Pentaho (Modified JavaScript) panel using the following code but it doesn't return an array

```
var sample = participant
var sample2= sample.split(',');
```

Comment: 'Participant' is a string?

Comment: Participant is filed name

Comment: I mean the value for 'Participant' field. Is it string?

Comment: yes they are string